# how to set font for components using style sheet in c#?

Tags: c#, css

`stylesheet.css`

```
body
    {
        font-family:Tahoma;
    }
    Label
    {
        font-family:Freestyle Script;
    }
    Hyperlink
    {
        font-family:Times New Roman;
    }
    TextBox
    {
        font-family:Tahoma;
    }
```

`index.aspx`

`<link rel="Stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />`

Its not being afffected for hyperlink & label and not setting different font for both.

My components are in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET renders html at client side and css is applied to html. You cannot use HyperLink , Label etc.

```
Label renders to <Span>
Hyperlink to <a>
TextBox to <Input>
```

try

```
a
{
    font-family:Times New Roman;
}
input
{
    font-family:Tahoma;
}
```

Instead, its better to assign ID's to them and use the ids to apply css.

Comment: how do I assign IDs? It has been done for hyperlink using a but input is not working.and with input how will I differentiate for label and textbox?

Comment: <asp:label id ="xyz"/> \and in css use #xyz {font-family:Times New Roman;
}  id is available for all asp controls.

Comment: Also you have to add ClientIDMode="Static" to get the same id at client side.

Comment: It works, but if you use to set css style to span, a, input like this, all other span, a, and input elements on your page will be applied with same styles. Just try and learn to use ID's and classes to differentiate elements on a page and apply styles to them separately, which will be a good practice to do. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's label, not Lable.
Use

```
a
{
  ...
}
```

Instead of hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

u can assign class to controls in aspx file as

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass ="txtInput" />
```

and in css file

```
 .txtInput
   {
     font-family:Tahoma;
   }
```